# Renaming headers in R

Tags: r

I want to rename headers of four dataframes (dw,ds,dmw,dne). All of them have six columns.

```
regions <- c("dw","ds","dmw","dne")
for (i in regions){
names(i)=c("lon","lat","area","fd","tp","rt")
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in names(i) = c("lon", "lat", "area", "fd", "tp", "rt") : 
'names' attribute [6] must be the same length as the vector [1]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `colnames` instead and use `get` to refer to the variable:

```
for (i in regions){
    dat <- get(i)
    colnames(dat) <- c("lon","lat","area","fd","tp","rt")
    assign(i, dat)
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I am getting this error.

    Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("lon", "lat", "area",     "fd", "tp",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Comment: Sweet! Yes, it works. Still not sure where I went wrong first time. Looked simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say this is more the R way to approach this using lists.  Storing your data in a list makes your life easier (most of the time), particularly when you want to do repeated manipulations of individual elements (in this case `data.frame`s).  Here I use `lapply` because you want to change the names in a consistent manner, but with `mapply` you could change each `data.frame` individually with different names.

**First create some data like you should have done** -  I assigned to the global environment as I believe you have.

```
dw <- mtcars[1:4, 1:6]
ds <- mtcars[1:4, 1:6]
dmw <- mtcars[1:4, 1:6]
dne <- mtcars[1:4, 1:6]
```

**Now wrap all that goodness up as a list (or better yet read it in/create as a list if you can)**

```
lst <- list(dw, ds, dmw, dne)
## name the list
names(lst) <- c("dw","ds","dmw","dne")

## Now we can use lapply to add the column names    
(out <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
    setNames(x, nm = c("lon","lat","area","fd","tp","rt"))
}))
```

I'd continue to operate out of the list and manipulate individual elements/objects in the list using indexing (see what `out[["dw"]]` gives you).  If you really want to reassign to the global environment use `list2env`:

```
list2env(out, envir = .GlobalEnv)
dne
```

Comment: `setNames` would like be convenient here as well.

Comment: @joran, never even tried it, nice, I likes (and included in the answer).

Comment: Thanks. One question: How is this way superior to the other answer? What are the benefits of lapply?

Comment: It's not about superior, it's about efficiency.  If you are dealing with multiple of anything (in this case data frames) and you are doing the same manipulation to these multiple things (data frames) you write less code and work faster in a list than multiple objects in the global environment.  It's like saying "I have these four lawn tools I ned to return to the store"  Should you drive to the store 4 times and return each one separately, or drive there once?  It's not about how we answered the question, the point is more about how you're approaching handling your data.