# Change dataframes names in loop in R

Tags: r

I have a set of data frames with names RI** where ** denotes different numbers. All of them contains same data for different periods. I want change columns names of all these data frames. I wrote:

```
varNames <- c('varName1','varName2',...)
dfList <- c('RI11','RI12',...)
for (i in dfList) {colnames(i) <- varNames}
```

But this doesn't help. I got message "Error in names(i) <- varNames : 
  'names' attribute [15] must be the same length as the vector [1]"

I tried to use apply function but did not get it.

Comment: Duplicate -- see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386943/renaming-headers-in-r

Answer (score 0):

I would use `setNames`:

```
 dfList <- lapply(dfList,setNames,varNames)
```